# Has Lois Lane ever gotten killed and been brought back to life?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Has Lois Lane ever gotten killed in the comics and been brought back to life?

Comment: It didn't want to let me ask this question. Is it really that bad?

Comment: I think this question is overly broad. The number of circumstances where Lois has been nearly killed, believed to be killed, or was temporarily dead would likely be a list far longer than anyone could compile effectively. Is there any way to refine this in some fashion?

Comment: @Book Worm First of all: Welcome to the site! Second: It's not a bad question, it's just a little bit brief. Check out the FAQ section for some helpful hints. :)

Comment: @Thaddeus - since the question is "has?" you can answer with one case where she was definitely dead. I know of two (in *Smallville* where Superman flash-freezes her and then thaws out; and in one of the movies where she dies in earthquake and he turns back time to save her). But that's not in comics. If you can't choose one, pick the earliest, OR the most dramatic :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Action #795, the metahuman Manchester Black, after surviving a fight with Superman which resulted in Superman performing a partial lobotomy and temporarily removing Black's powers, Black exacts his revenge by apparently killing Lois Lane.**

[image: Manchester Black stands over the body of Lois Lane]

*Manchester Black stands over the body of Lois Lane*

Black's goal is to enrage Superman into losing his status as the premiere metahuman of Earth by killing him. He taunts Superman incessantly, pointing out how Superman made Lois vulnerable and telling him she was never safe as long as she was with him.

[image: Superman kills Manchester Black]

*Superman kills Manchester Black*

[image]

Fortunately for Superman, Black was unable to truly create an event in which Superman would grieve Lois and exact revenge for her death.

[image]

She wakens from Black's mental domination, they reconcile and Black slinks away, erasing Luthor's memory of Superman's secret ID before killing himself. This death of Lois Lane while a psychic construct, was considered pivotal because it showed Superman, even in the light of the death of Lois, to be more interested in Justice than Vengeance. Manchester Black was the ultimate anti-hero who desired more than anything else to prove the era of the superhero was over.

Comment: So....no, then.